# limiting tags to use with ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm currently evaluating whether to use ActsAsTaggableOn or roll my own.
I can't have users create tags at random but want to define a list of allowed tags for a project model. Users associated with that project can only select the tags that are allowed for that project (through project and tag model where a project can have multiple tags).
The sane thing to do seems to use ActsAsTaggableOn, but after googling for more than one hour I can't find a lot of documentation on my use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  haven't used ActsAsTaggableOn but if your only issue is retricting what tags can be selected, that should be easy.

Use a gem like `chosen-rails` to make a nice selector to choose tags from an array of allowed tags that you supply.  The returned array of selected tags are assigned to your acts_as_taggable_on field.

If the ActsAsTaggableOn doesn't support array input (I'm not clear on that) make the array an attr_accessor field such as `tag_array` and then do

```
my_object.my_tags = tag_array.join(',')
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm already using select2 so will incorporate it that way.